# Xamarin App Keeps Freezing After Running MySql Query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, xamarin, mobile

### **Objective**

User enters a value in a simple textbox. This value is stored in a variable and is then passed as a parameter into an SQL query. The output of this query is the final result which needs to be displayed under the textbox.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()

        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void HandleTextChange(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.NewTextValue);
        }

        public void HandleEnterPress(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Pressed");
            Label newTodo = new Label();
            var methodOneReturn = MethodOne(InputField.Text);
            newTodo.Text = Convert.ToString(methodOneReturn.Result);
            newTodo.FontSize = 20;
            TodoList.Children.Add(newTodo);
        }

public static async Task<Tuple<decimal>> MethodOne(string rawInput)

        {
            decimal output = 0;
            string strConnectionString = "some string";
            var conn = new MySqlConnection(strConnectionString);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToString(ex));
            }

            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = $@"MySql Query {rawInput}";

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = (MySqlDataReader) await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        output = reader.GetDecimal(0);
                        //Console.WriteLine($"Reading from table: {reader.GetDecimal(0):C2}");
                    }
                }
            }

            return Tuple.Create(output);
        }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ToDoListApp.MainPage">
    
    <StackLayout>

        <Frame BackgroundColor="Gray" Padding="10,5,10,5"  CornerRadius="0">
            <Entry Text=""
                   Background="White"
                   Placeholder="Enter a ToDo"
                   TextChanged="HandleTextChange"
                   Completed="HandleEnterPress"
                   x:Name="InputField"
            />
        </Frame>

        <StackLayout x:Name="TodoList">
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

### **Problem**

When a snippet of .CS code (Tuple Method) is ran in console program, it runs perfectly fine. However, when the same code is ran in Xamarin app (android), after entering string in textbox, the app freezes. In debugging mode, the app freezes after executing this line:

```
using (MySqlDataReader reader = (MySqlDataReader) await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
```

Your help will be much appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: You need to use async/await when calling async methods

Comment: Console apps [don't have synchronization context](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) which is why there is no deadlock when you run it that way.

Comment: To clarify Jason's comment: to avoid "deadlock", do `async/await` **all the way from the top**. DO NOT use `.Result`; MainThread is deadlocked due to that. Do `var methodOneReturn = await MethodOne(InputField.Text);`. One way to make this possible, is to declare `public async void HandleEnterPress(...` There are other ways to get into an async context; search `xamarin await freezes`.

Comment: Thanks guys for your input.

@ToolmakerSteve
This did solve the problem. Much appreciated. What is the best source for learning about MySQL related operations under the context of Xamarin Forms, especially concerning async/await?

Comment: Look for any articles about "use of await" with i/o. Look for mention of background threads vs main (UI or dispatcher) thread when using `await`.